# Using AMD IGX for X/Wayland and Nvidia 1050Ti for gaming?

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-prime, integrated

Here's my setup

Mobo - Gigabyte 890gpa-ud3h
Integrated graphics - AMD HD4290
Discrete card: nvidia 1050TI
Monitor - 2 HDMI inputs available; currently only using nvidia card
OS: KDE neon

Considerations:

1. KDE and Nvidia don't really work well - screen tearing, wayland doens't work at all...AMD has better support.
2. For gaming, I'd obviously like to use the more powerful nvidia card.
3. I have space for only a single monitor - so not looking for a dual output setup etc. I can switch inputs on the monitor.
4. Given the very old motherboard without IOMMU, GPU passthrough to a VM isn't an option.

What I'd like to do:

1. Use both integrated card and nvidia at hte same time with desktop primarily running off the integrated card.
2. Launch games (mine are all on steam), use Nvidia card.

Is this possible? Arch wiki page seems to say so https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PRIME - but probably someone who has such a setup can help?

How far I've got:
1. BIOS is configured properly and if I set the IGX as primary, lscpi lists two VGA cards. However, X does not start - this is likely due to the fact that I haven't touched my X config.

- Will this work on a desktop? Or is it laptop only (hw wise?)
- How do I tell X that there are two graphics cards?
- Will this work with nivdia proprietary driver? after all, the whole point is better game perf - so using os driver isn't an option.
- Can I make one of them be used only for X rendering and the other one solely for games?
- Or do I have to have them mirrored so that they both render the same visual? Then when launching games, launch with teh DRI_PRIME=1 so that the nvidia card is used?

I realize that many of these may be answered on the arch wiki but I'm looking for some clear answers before I go mucking around my system.

:confused:

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting thread, I will not provide a full howto here, but I recommend you to following this excellent guide :

```
https://davidyat.es/2016/09/08/gpu-passthrough/
```

Regarding your question, here the answer :

- As far as I know, there is no reason that is not working on a Laptop. But for compatibility reason and performance, I suggest a desktop anyway.
- Configuring two graphics card is a bit tricky with Xorg, I personally prefer the KVM way (one normal desktop on the integrated graphic card + one gaming graphic card configured as passthrough in a kvm virtual machine).
- Based on my solution, as soon as you would like to play games, you just start the virtual machine and switch to another screen. The guest virtual machine can use proprietary nvidia drivers if needed.
- Based on my solution, one will be used for the normal desktop, one graphic card dedicated for a virtual machine for gaming.
- For last question, this is not applicable as the nvidia graphic card will never be used by the host, only the virtual machine.

Big advantage of the virtualized solution, you can choose the guest operating system. You need to play a game on M$, no problem, create a virtual machine with this OS.

Comment: gpu passthrough requires IOMMU support in the Mobo.. So a non starter for me